How to solve System.UnauthorizedAccessException on multi instance Azure App service
I have a search API that created by Lucene .Net.
I deployed it on an Azure App Service and set 2 instance with load blancing.
The Lucene index has been put on Blob Storage and will be update by API's background service.
2 instance have 2 index folder independently.
Everything run well. But sometime System.UnauthorizedAccessException occurs when update the index folder.
Update the index folder process like following:
There are Master and Slave folders. When update index, my API will access to Slave folder to get data. When updating index is end, my API will access to Master.

Download index on Blob Storage
Delete Master/Slave folder and create new folder
Extract index file into new Master/Slave folder

I think that when API is being requested, we cannot delete Master/Slave folder and create new folder.
Does anyone have experience with this?
Thanks in advance.

As a workaround for you:
use 2 different directories for your current data and updated and just do the switch between them in your app. Basically:

In folder A is live state, it is used and active. Remove old stuff from your B folder, upload your new index to folder B.
Do the switch between A - B. Now is the folder B live.
Optionally clean up the folder A

This way you have more control and the switch happens immediate, you do not have any wait times.
